# Select from two tables only that rows that satisfies multiple conditions in second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are 3 tables:

- posts
- posts_tags
- tags

Is it possible to select only that posts that have 2 and more certain tags?

For selection all posts with certain tag I do this

```
SELECT * FROM posts, tags WHERE posts.id=tags.id_post AND post_tags.id_tag=1
```

I tried this query but it gives me posts that have post_tags.id_tag=1 or post_tags.id_tag=2

```
SELECT * FROM posts, tags WHERE posts.id=post_tags.id_post AND post_tags.id_tag IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Join doesn't solve this problem @RuchishParikh

Comment: @RuchishParikh, he's already doing a join (an implicit one.)

Comment: Typically there would be 3 tables: `posts`, `tags`, and a table that says which tags belong to which posts e.g.`post_tag`

Comment: please show the table structure for better understanding

Comment: Show us the 3 tables columns so we can answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM posts
JOIN tags ON posts.id = tags.id_post
WHERE tags.id IN(1, 2)
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING COUNT(tags.id_post) >= 2
```

Comment: It's not about count of tags. I need to select only that posts that have 2 and more CERTAIN tags. For example tags with id=1 and id=2

Comment: you have a problem with the group by clause not matching posts.*

Comment: IN condition means 1 OR 2. I need AND conditiong

Comment: @ArsenIbragimov The HAVING clause takes care of that. Note that this solution assumes a UNIQUE (or PK) index on `(id_post_id,tag)`

Comment: Assuming that tags are not unique you need to switch to `COUNT(DISTINCT tags.id_post)`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly -

```
SELECT postName,count(*) as times                -- you can add fields or omit the count(*)
FROM 
(select * from posts where id in (1,2) posts     -- you can replace the whole line with `posts`. this way gives you more room for conditions
inner join 
(select * from tags where id_post in (1,2)) tags -- same as @posts
on posts.id=tags.id_post 
group by postName                                -- if you added some fieldNames at the first line - add them here too..
having times>=2
                                                 -- AND tags.id=1 -- you can specify more conditions here
```